# Why am I getting a Non-existent class error in PHP on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, php, nginx

I've set up an Nginx/PHP (both installed from Yum) environment on my Fedora 15 install, but I've run into a strange issue.

I have some projects that use Codeigniter (1.6), but they keep getting the following error:

> Non-existent class: Content

The full output almost looks as if PHP starts parsing the Content.php file, but then stops partway through:

> {$var})) { $this->{$var} = ''; } $this->{$var} .= ob_get_clean(); } }
>
> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Non-existent class: Content

The contents of Content.php are:

```
<?

class Content {

    function capture() {
    ob_start();
    }

    function __get($name) {
    return '';
    }

    function content_for($var) {
    if (!isset($this->{$var})) { //It stops on this line
        $this->{$var} = '';
    }
    $this->{$var} .= ob_get_clean();
    }

}
```

What's odd to me is that this exact same setup works just fine on Ubuntu (the projects using this setup have been live for some time, I've also set it up on several Ubuntu machines for development and have never run into this problem. I also know that PHP itself works, in general, as I can run a basic site that uses a little bit of PHP, as well as some projects that use a different framework.

From what I can tell, it runs through a number of other PHP files before getting to Content.php (it has to, just to even get to the point that tells it to load Content to begin with), so PHP works, at least for a time, but then it seems to suddenly die. There aren't any other errors in the log files, either.

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should compare the files `php.ini` used by Fedora and Ubuntu. There are probably a few different settings that make the difference.

Comment: @nozimica - That was it. Turns out Fedora has short_open_tags off by default. Turning it on fixed the issue. If you want to put you comment as an answer, I'd gladly mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: It's been added as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the files `php.ini` used by Fedora and Ubuntu. There are probably a few different settings that make the difference.